# Vue transition with v-if and v-else not working

Tags: animation, vue.js, transition

I cant add animation using transition or transition-group. I have code:

```
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
        <div key=1 v-if="$route.name !== null">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>
        <div v-else key=2>
            <p>First text</p>
            <p>Second text</p>
        </div>
    </transition>
```

the change does not help from `transtition` to `transition-group`. Transition should surround:

```
<div v-if="$route.name !== null">
   <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

and

```
<p>First tex</p>
<p>Second text</p>
```

Comment: I want to confirm that you *do* see "First text" and "Second text" without the animation, since `null` is quite an odd thing to have as a name. I would expect it to be either `undefined` or a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I used `transition` two times. I do not know if I should do it, but it works now.

```
    <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
        <div key="save" v-if="$route.name !== null">
             <transition mode="out-in" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
            <router-view></router-view>
            </transition>
        </div>
        <div v-else key="edit">
           <p>First tex</p>
           <p>Second text</p>
        </div>
    </transition>
```